# Using asynchronous Nightwatch After Hook with client interaction does not work

Tags: nightwatch.js, cucumberjs

As far as I can tell, using promises or callbacks in `After` hook prevents Command Queue from executing when using promises / callbacks. I'm trying to figure out why, any help or suggestions are appreciated. Closest issue I could find on github is: https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/341

which states: `finding that trying to make browser calls in the after hook is too late; it appears that the session is closed before after is run.` (exactly my problem). But there is no solution provided. I need to run cleanup steps after my scenarios run, and those cleanup steps need to be able to interact with browser.

https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Understanding-the-Command-Queue

In the snippet below, `bar` is never outputted. Just `foo`.

```
const { After } = require('cucumber');
const { client } = require('nightwatch-cucumber');

After(() => new Promise((resolve) => {
  console.log('foo')
  client.perform(() => {
    console.log('bar')
  });
}));
```

I also tried using callback approach

```
After((browser, done) => {
  console.log('foo');
  client.perform(() => {
    console.log('bar');
    done();
  });
});
```

But similar to 1st example, `bar` is never outputted, just `foo`

You can instead use something like:

```
const moreWork = async () => {
  console.log('bar');
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 10000);
  })
}

After(() => client.perform(async () => {
  console.log('foo');
  moreWork();
}));
```

But the asynchronous nature of `moreWork` means that the client terminates before my work is finished, so this isn't really workin for me. You can't use an `await` in the `perform` since they are in different execution contexts.

Basically the only way to get client commands to execute in after hook is my third example, but it prevents me from using async.

The 1st and 2nd examples would be great if the command queue didn't freeze and prevent execution.

edit: I'm finding more issues on github that state the browser is not available in before / after hooks: https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/575

What are you supposed to do if you want to clean up using the browser after all features have run?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
After(async () => {
   await client.perform(() => {
      ...
   });
   await moreWork();
})
```

Comment: You may be right. I'll return with a definitive answer soon.